# if I give image path like foldername/picture name it display On windows platoform but not in Android in xamarin

Tags: android, ios, windows, xamarin

BackgroundImage="Picture/abc.jpg"

in content page  I have added this but it not display image in android display in UWP Project

Comment: please read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

Please put your Image in to the Resource folder like following screenshot.
[image]

Then use it in xamarin forms.

In your situation, you can put your image to Resource, then set it like following code.

```
MyImage.Source = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? ImageSource.FromFile("hk,jpg") : ImageSource.FromFile("Picture/abc.jpg");
```

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.